# Who to add X-Frame-Options to Authentik?

Tags: nginx, header, single-sign-on, x-frame-options

currently i am working on my HomeLab infrastructure. Unfortunately, I ran into a problem that I can't solve.

The following components are affected

- Nginx Proxy Manager
- Authentik
- Dashy

My goal is to have all my services in one UI with a single authentication-flow. Dashy has the ability to show different services inside the dashboard ui. That works fine as long as I set the X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM URL" and Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors URL" in Nginx Proxy Manager.

Unfortunately, however, Authentik now seems to override the X-Frame options and ignore changes in the proxy manager. And because Authentik is always addressed via a redirect before the first call of a service, I can't load an application within an IFrame.

Now to my question:

- How do I give Authentik to understand that it should allow SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW FROM if it ignores the nginx configuration. Is there an Option that let me set headers for Authentik?

[X-Frame Options after edit the nginx proxymanager conf.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0YsR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

were you able to make any progress on this issue. In the same boat but using Organizr.

Best

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding this instructions to the proxy conf under **nginx/proxy_host** 
`add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM my.domain";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors my.domain my.domain";`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!
Added to my / location for my authentik site but receive the following error from Chrome:

Refused to frame 'https://auth.mysite.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://auth.mysite.com".

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There was hardly ever much support for ALLOW-FROM, today it is only relevant for an evironment that still runs IE11, see https://caniuse.com/?search=allow-from

All modern browsers support CSP frame-ancestors and with that directive present would ignore X-Frame-Options. If you are successful in setting CSP frame-ancestors you could ignore X-Frame-Options fully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already configured my nginx proxy manger with the these header.
`add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM myserver.com";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors myserver.com";`
It seems like authentik overrides these directives. At my other subdomains this solves the problem but authentik ignore it.